# xbmc/video/VideoInfoScanner: Cannot retrieve Music Video

Tags: kodi

I am trying to retrieve information for a Music Video. For instance let's take:

```
$ youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio' --merge-output-format mp4 https://youtu.be/GhNuAXnhADI
```

If I start kodi, and try to search based on the filename I get no result, so I tried to simplify and enter in the text box, simply: "Come on home":

[image]

I still get no result:

```
21:43:38.887 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: Thread VideoInfoDownloader start, auto delete: false
21:43:38.888 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: FindMovie: Searching for 'Come on Home' using TheAudioDb.com for Music Videos scraper (path: '/home/mathieu/.kodi/addons/metadata.musicvideos.theaudiodb.com', content: 'musicvideos', version: '1.3.3')
21:43:38.888 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: scraper: CreateSearchUrl returned <url>http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&amp;t=</url>
21:43:38.888 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: CurlFile::Open(0x55555c3ba0f0) http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&t=
21:43:39.009 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: Get: Using content of "http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&t=" as binary or text with "UTF-8" charset
21:43:39.009 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: scraper: GetSearchResults returned <results sorted="yes"></results>
21:43:39.010 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: FindMovie: Searching for 'Come on Home' using TheAudioDb.com for Music Videos scraper (path: '/home/mathieu/.kodi/addons/metadata.musicvideos.theaudiodb.com', content: 'musicvideos', version: '1.3.3')
21:43:39.011 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: scraper: CreateSearchUrl returned <url>http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&amp;t=</url>
21:43:39.011 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: CurlFile::Open(0x55555c3ba0f0) http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&t=
21:43:39.073 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: Get: Using content of "http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&t=" as binary or text with "UTF-8" charset
21:43:39.073 T:140736808257280   DEBUG: scraper: GetSearchResults returned <results sorted="yes"></results>
```

Which seems to be consistent with a command line GET query:

```
$ curl "http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Come%20on%20Home&t="
{"track":null}%
```

However if I now go online, I can find a hit:

- http://www.theaudiodb.com/track/32777980

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [API query URL](http://www.theaudiodb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7) I figured I needed to tweak a bit the title + artist line.

[image]

Pay attention that spaces before/after the dash are important.

[image]

So eventually I get something to work:

```
21:52:33.568 T:140736062281472   DEBUG: CurlFile::Open(0x55555c3c9130) http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Franz%20Ferdinand&t=Come%20on%20home
21:52:33.568 T:140736062281472    INFO: easy_acquire - Created session to http://www.theaudiodb.com
21:52:33.829 T:140736062281472   DEBUG: Get: Using content of "http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/searchtrack.php?s=Franz%20Ferdinand&t=Come%20on%20home" as binary or text with "UTF-8" charset
21:52:33.830 T:140736062281472   DEBUG: scraper: GetSearchResults returned <results sorted="yes"><entity><title>Franz Ferdinand - Come On Home [Franz Ferdinand]</title><url cache="tadb-32777980.json">http://www.theaudiodb.com/api/v1/json/18626d636d76696473706d/track.php?h=32777980</url></entity></results>
21:52:33.830 T:140736062281472   DEBUG: Thread VideoInfoDownloader 140736062281472 terminating
```

So I need to use ${ARTIST NAME} - ${SONG NAME} to get eventually something.